# How to get a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to extract the values from a dictionary and print them as a list. For example: If i have
`letter = {"i": 3, "o": 2, "u": 2}`

and want to extract `3`,`2`, and `2` and print it as a list

`[3, 2, 2]`
How do I do this? 
I've tried

`print([x[::] for x in letter])`

However, this prints out `['i', 'o', 'u']` and not `[3, 2, 2]`.
Thank you for the help in advanced :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a method in Python called .keys() that allows you to get the keys from a dict.  Similarly, there is also a method called values() for the converse.

These are dict instance methods, ie:

```
myDict = { "i": 0, "t": 1, "f": 2 }
print(myDict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call dict.values()
[Further details here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)

Comment: when I use dict.values(letter) it returns dict_values([3, 2, 2]) however i want it to just return [3, 2, 2]. How do i do this?

Comment: list(dict.values())

Comment: @Zooby: If you're using a recent version of Python you can also do `[*letter.values()]`. Bear in mind that a plain `dict` is an unordered collection, so the ordering of the values list may not be what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try `letter.values()`, which gives you `dict_values([3, 2, 2])`

```
>>> letter = {"i": 3, "o": 2, "u": 2}
>>> print(list(letter.values()))
[3, 2, 2]
```